# Vector3 non floating point?

Tags: c#, vector, struct

Is it possible to change C#'s built-in Vector3 struct to not use floating point Singles and instead use ints or bytes for performance reasons?

Comment: Possible to change as in *swap out*? No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to make your own `Vector3` struct based on integer or byte operations.  This is entirely possible, as there is not a single "built-in" `Vector3` (there are multiple implementations of 3D Vectors in the framework).

However, you will need to convert to the framework version if you plan to use it in framework API calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own Vector3, or use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

However, if you call something that is expecting a `Vector3`, they will *not* be expecting your type.  You must use a standard `Vector3` in such a situation.

Comment: Note that the framework Tuple types are all classes, not structs.  Depending on the goal, that may not be appropriate here...

Answer (score 1):

As it is already pointed out you can't change any existing type (including Vector3d) to use different types for its members (unless it is generic and designed to do so). You need to create your own (make sure to know differences between `class` and `struct` when you do so).

If performance is concern you need to try and carefully measure for your particular case - it is very unclear if significant savings will come out of such change.

Changing float to int will not give you space savings and may complicate computations (i.e. 1.5*1.5 is easy in floats, while if you are using scaled ints it will require extra operation 15*15/100, and sin/cos used for rotation may not work so well either).

Changing float to byte will give you space savings, but math will be more complicated and always force conversion to/from int for all manipulations.